# How to disable Hadoop Kerberos

Tags: hadoop, kerberos

I used a internal script to setup a Hadoop cluster. It configured Hadoop security with Kerberos by default. This is very inconvenient for a developing environment.

I googled a lot, but the results are all about "how to enable ...".

Please help to give some reference or advice.

Answer (score 3):

Change the values for:

**core-site.xml(HDFS):**

1. `hadoop.security.authentication` to `simple`
2. `hadoop.security.authorization` to `false`

**hdfs-site.xml(HDFS):**

1. `dfs.datanode.address` to `50010`
2. `dfs.datanode.http.address` to `50075`

**hbase-site.xml(HBASE):**

1. `hbase.security.authentication` to `simple`
2. `hbase.security.authorization` to `false`
3. Comment these properties if present: `hbase.regionserver.kerberos.principal`, `hbase.regionserver.keytab.file`, `hbase.master.kerberos.principal`, `hbase.master.keytab.file`, `hbase.rpc.engine`.

**zoo.cfg:**

1. Comment these line if present: `kerberos.removeHostFromPrincipal=true`, `kerberos.removeRealmFromPrincipal=true`

**Permission:**

Change the HDFS data directory permission to `755`. Search for `dfs.data.dir` in `hdfs-site.xml`.

> **Do these changes on all nodes. Restart your cluster and check if its disabled.**

Reference: https://groups.google.com/a/cloudera.org/forum/#!topic/cdh-user/7_1DEdpdY3E

Comment: Do I need to modify other related settings, such as: 
    <property> 
          <name>dfs.block.access.token.enable</name>  
          <value>true</value> 
    </property>