# Hadoop enable simple authentication

Tags: java, authentication, hadoop, kerberos

I tried the steps listed here [How to disable Hadoop Kerberos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29744821/how-to-disable-hadoop-kerberos) but my datanode wouldn't start because of this exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Does not contain a valid host:port authority: 50010
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.createSocketAddr(NetUtils.java:212)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.createSocketAddr(NetUtils.java:164)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.createSocketAddr(NetUtils.java:153)
```

I have apache hadoop 2.6 installed on a CentOS vm.  I started hadoop with `start-dfs.sh` and `start-yarn.sh`.  I'm trying to connect to hadoop from a java client with hdfs protocol but I am getting the below exception.

```
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException): SIMPLE authentication is not enabled.  Available:[TOKEN]
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1468)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1399)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:232)
```

I've seen a similar exception posted a few times by other people but it usually ends in `[TOKEN, KERBEROS]`.  Do I need to enable KERBEROS authentication or is TOKEN something else?  Ideally I would like to just use simple authentication. If I can't use simple authentication would installing CDH4 satisfy the TOKEN authentication?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I was sending my request to the node address port I got from localhost:8088 and not port 8020 or whatever port is specified in fs.defaultFS in core-site.xml.